# Google Chrome: Is there any flag to disable the need of user interact to fullscreen a video

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen, flags

In chrome you can make a video fullscreen using `requestFullscreen()`, but there's a problem: It requires user interaction. Autoplay without mute has the same problem, but it can be solved using `--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required`. So my question: Is there any chrome flag for fullscreen?

PS: I know about `--start-fullscreen`, but I don't want the sites to be set to fullscreen when starting the browser.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case on why exactly you need this functionality? Taking over the full screen without the user’s explicit consent or expectation is objectively horrendous UX, and it wouldn’t surprise me if there wasn’t a flag built into Chromium to modify this behavior.

Comment: Well, Is hard to say.. but, you know, tomorrow is april first

Comment: @esqew the question is about chrome flags, these are generally used for development rather than user-facing functionality. Developers have all kinds of reasons for disabling default browser behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

You may try:

```
  --disable-gesture-requirement-for-presentation
```

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/